# Can I use CSS `position:sticky` outside the parent container?

Tags: html, css, css-position, sticky

My markdown looks something like -

```
<body>
  <header>
   <div class"logo" />
   <div class"contact-info" />
   <div class="sticky-navigation"/>
  </header>
<main>
  <!-- content -->
</main>
</body>
```

I need to make the div with class `sticky-navigation` behave like a sticky navigation when the user scrolls through body. Is there a way to use `position:sticky` to do the same?

As far as I've seen, the use of `position:sticky` is highly dependent on the markup and will only work on the whole of `<header/>`.

Comment: Just for clarificaiton, do you want it to stick only after scrolling to a certain position?

Comment: @tjvg1991 I want it to sticky as soon as it touches the top of the viewport.

Comment: try this https://teamtreehouse.com/community/forum-tip-create-a-sticky-navigation-with-css-and-jquery-2

Answer (score -3):

```css
position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
    top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
```

If you are using just css - than you can use position:fixed

Comment: A sticky behavior is different from position fixed.

Comment: yes, but please check caniuse - you will see it is also browser dependent, not all of them support it and you need to add browser specs in css

Comment: I'm adding a polyfill for browser support. That isn't a concern.